# Bootstrap Pagination not working with displayed content

Tags: javascript, pagination

Want to make dynamic bootstrap pagination with displaying different content on clicking Paginations.

Comment: You have some example code please?

Comment: if you want use a table take a look at [Bootstrap Table Pagination](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#pagination-table).

Comment: Want to use div not table

Comment: Ok please do an effort search for us an example of what you want to do.

Comment: Example that you gave with table is ok, but i just want div instead of table

Comment: Basically, i want to show content on click pagination numbers,please help. if you have any example, send me link,thanks

Comment: How to set positioning of slide out form toggle button in mobile for good responsiveness?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this, I hope this will work for you**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//raw.github.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/master/lib/jquery.bootpag.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main" style="text-align:center;">
            <h2 style="text-align:center;">Pagination with Div Structur</h2>
            <div class='blk content4'>
                <!--// show here ur div structure-->
                Pagination content here.
            </div>
            <div class="pagi"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.pagi').bootpag({
                total: 27,
                page: 1,
                maxVisible: 5,
                leaps: true,
                firstLastUse: true,
                first: '<span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span>',
                last: '<span aria-hidden="true">&rarr;</span>',
                wrapClass: 'pagination',
                activeClass: 'active',
                disabledClass: 'disabled',
                nextClass: 'next',
                prevClass: 'prev',
                lastClass: 'last',
                firstClass: 'first'
            }).on("page", function (event, num) {
                $(".content4").html("Page " + num); // or some ajax content loading...
            }).find('.pagination');
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```